# Защита вопроса защищает и от удаления Духом сообщества?

Tags: поддержка, дух-сообщества, удаление-вопросов

Если на вопросе стоит защита, то означает ли это, что он не будет удалён Духом сообщества независимо от рейтинга и наличия ответов?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет.

О такой защите не сказано ни на странице с описанием [защиты вопросов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52764/what-is-a-protected-question), ни на странице с описанием [автоудаления вопросов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). В описании защиты упоминается только защита от юзеров, не имеющих 10 репы (бонусные 100 игнорируются, кстати). В описании автоудаления упоминаются только проверки на *заблокированность* вопроса. Блокировка вопроса (не путать с защитой) — это возможность, доступная только ромбовым модераторам, и она блокирует вопрос для всех, а не только для низкореповых юзеров.

Надо отметить, что защита вопросов также работает в автоматическом режиме: если за 24 часа было удалено 3 или более ответа от низкореповых юзеров, то вопрос будет защищён силами Духа сообщества. Так как привилегия позволяет защищать вопрос только спустя сутки после публикации, то практического смысла в такой возможности нет.